# Bash script find and replace string with variable that contains complex special characters without having to escape?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, replace, string-literals

Is there a simpler way to replace a string with a variable literally that contains all complex characters without needing to do character escaping?

```
complex='~`!@#$%^&*()-_=+\|]}{[;:/?.>,<\/*&\#/'
sed -i "s/secret\ =\ \".*/secret\ =\ \"$complex\"/g" ./file.txt
```

I already know that `&` `\` and `/` are the problems. I can do all manner of cleaning with sed commands, but is there a simpler way? Is there a way I can literally make sed read that variable as is?

My work around for now is the following, but even this does not work with `/` properly ...

```
complex='~`!@#$%^&*()-_=+\|]}{[;:/?.>,<\/*&\#/'
psk_bs="$(echo $complex | sed 's/\\/\\\\\\/g')"
psk_bs_amp="$(echo "$psk_bs" | sed 's/\&/\\&/g')"
psk_bs_amp_fs="$(echo "$psk_bs_amp" | sed 's,'/','\/',g')"
sed -i "s/secret\ =\ \".*/secret\ =\ \"$psk_bs_amp_fs\"/g" ./file.txt
```

Comment: How much do you care about using sed specifically, and not any other tool? [BashFAQ #21](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021) shows how you to do literal replace operations with either awk (see `gsub_literal` defined at the end) or perl (see the "Just Tell Me What To Do" section).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can do all manner of cleaning with sed commands, but is there a simpler way? Is there a way I can literally make sed read that variable as is?

I'm afraid there is not. But character escaping is not as a big deal as you make it seem to be. This'll work just fine:

```
psk=$(sed 's/[/&\]/\\&/g' <<< $complex)
sed -i "s/secret = \".*/secret = \"$psk\"/g" ./file.txt
```

With bash 5.2 you don't even need sed for escaping:

```
psk=${complex//[\/&\\]/\\&}
```